# Google Reply to Reviews API only return results of last 7 days

Tags: node.js, google-api, androidpublisher

I'm trying to connect to Reply to Reviews API and get my app reviews, I do get them, but it only return results from the last 7 days. According to Google docs it needs to return:

```
  {
    "pageInfo": {},
    "reviews": [],
    "tokenPagination": {}
  }
```

But it only return the reviews inside the array and there is no `tokenPagination` or `pageInfo`.

The last time I tried to get the results (few months ago) everything was perfect and I do got the tokenPagination.

**api.js:**

```
const { google, androidpublisher_v3 } = require('googleapis');

const SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = 'service_account@email.iam.gserviceaccount.com';
const SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY_FILE = require('../KEY_FILE.json');

var auth;
var authClient;
var client;

class API {

  // When loading the singleton, authorize to googleapis
  constructor() {
    this.connect();
  }

  // Authorize to GoogleAPI
  async connect() {

    auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
      keyFile: './KEY_FILE.json',
      scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher']
    });
    
    authClient = await auth.getClient();
    client = await google.androidpublisher({ 
      version: 'v3',
      auth: authClient
    });
  }

  async reviews(bundleId) {
    // Fetch reviews by bundle identifier
    const createResponse = await client.reviews.list({
      packageName: bundleId,
      
    });

    var jsonResponse = JSON.stringify(createResponse);
    return createResponse;
  }
}

class Singleton {
  constructor() {
    if (!Singleton.instance) {
      Singleton.instance = new API();
    }
  }

  getInstance() {
    return Singleton.instance;
  }
}

module.exports = Singleton;
```

Anyone knows what may be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried setting maxResults?

Comment: Yeah I did, it does nothing..